# Connecting to a class inside a Silex route?

Tags: php, json, api, class, silex

I'm using Silex to create an API for my application, however I have already created classes and functions that does my logic and want to know if it's possible for Silex to call those from a route.

On the file that I'm using for the routing I want to be able to make a connection to my class and then use a function inside the route

```
require_once('..\class\class.php');
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/{id}', function (Silex\Application $app, $id) use () {

    $class = new Class();
    $data = $class->getData($id);
    $data = getData();

    return json_encode($data);
});
```

I want to call this from somewhere else passing through the id which will then be used to get the data, like this:

```
$response =file_get_contents('http://localhost/silex_test/api/router.php/'.$id);
```

Whenever I put the class connection, even in just the same file it doesn't return anything back, not even string. Is what I'm trying to do possible or have I completely misunderstood the capabilities of Silex?

Thanks in advance for any help, it would be greatly appreciated as I've spent days trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: show full code with `file_get_contents(...)`

Comment: @MaxP. It's just on my index page at the moment and I'm uisng var_dump to display. When I use silex's blog example it returns back so I don't think it's anything to do with that.

Comment: what happens if you open the browser and type this URL? Make sure to enable dev tools to see network status. You're probably having an error but you're missing it because the way you consume your api. BTW, what you want to do is 100% possible (with Silex or any other framework). You should reconfigure your HTTP server to avoid the *silex_test/api/router.php* part though (mod_rewrite, PHP dev server, etc.)

Comment: @mTorres I've tried running it through that URL but it doesn't return any errors, just a blank page. If I remove the class connection it can return the string. Do I need to declare the class somewhere in the route connection so Silex knows to use it?

Comment: @mTorres Thanks for your help. I switched the classes around and it started working. I followed the chain in the class that wasn't working and found that I had turned off error reporting for a reason I can't remember. Once back on it showed me I was missing a class declaration in the class that wasn't working. So more of a 'myself being stupid' issue, than a coding one.

Comment: Yeah, this happens to all of us. A PHP white page usually means a fatal error and a configuration which does not display errors :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing `$app->run();`. Place it after the call to `$app->get()`

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#usage